# Android device needs restart/reboot to get GPS locations after having GPS chip active a long time

Tags: android, gps, google-api-client

I'm developing yet another GPS tracking application for Android and I'm testing my code in Sony Xperia SP c5302 with Android 4.3.

I made a background service which uses Google Play Services' GoogleApiClient to get fused locations. I'm able to get locations fine but after a couple hours I realize my GPS chip stops returning locations because their accuracy raises from 10 to 30 or 50 (which means other providers than GPS are returning the new location).

Considering I'm indoors I thought the API decided to listen only to network providers, then I went to the street (with wifi and data connection turned off) and stopped getting fused locations at all (I wasn't getting network fixes anymore as expected and GPS chip was already dead as stated). Even Google Maps couldn't track me. Then I decided to just restart my phone at that very moment and I got GPS chip updates again just fine on both my application and Google Maps (wifi and data connection were still turned off).

I tried the same approach with the original Location API which used LocationManager with the same results.... I have to restart my phone in order for GPS chip to work again.

Here is my base code with GoogleApiClient:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

//GPS
private GoogleApiClient miGoogleApiClient = null;
private LocationRequest miLocationRequest = null;
private LocationRequest currLocation = null;

@Override  
public void onCreate() {     
    super.onCreate();     
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate MY SERVICE");

    startGPS();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    stopGPS();
}


public boolean startGPS(){
    Log.d(TAG, "startGPS");
    try{
        miGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(miConnectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(miOnConnectionFailedListener)
            .build();
        miGoogleApiClient.connect();

        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "can't start GPS:"+e);
        return false;
    }finally{return false;}
}

public void stopGPS(){
    Log.d(TAG, "stopGPS");
    miGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

private LocationListener miLocationListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:"+new Date(location.getTime())+", "+ location);
        //...more work
        currLocation = location;
    }
};

private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks miConnectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks(){
    @Override public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:"+bundle);
        currLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(miGoogleApiClient); //may be old
        miLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            //.setSmallestDisplacement(10) //Won't use this for now
            .setInterval(30000)
            .setFastestInterval(30000);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            miGoogleApiClient, miLocationRequest, miLocationListener);
    }
    @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int i){
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:"+i);
    }
};

private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener miOnConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener(){
    @Override public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:"+connectionResult);
    }
};

}
```

I know this approach drains battery faster but this application is meant for a specific client and not for general public so it's OK.

¿Is this behavior supposed to happen or there is something wrong with my phone or something wrong with my code? I find specially weird that even Google Maps can't get the location so I'm wondering if my application is messing with the phone itself.

Edit.

I have to restart the phone because turning off and on GPS from Android settings menu makes no difference. (My service log shows that GPS is started with no mistakes if I stop it and start it again)

Comment: Though it should do just the same, you could try using https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation in any case it saves you a lot of lines of code

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks. It's an interesting library. As you said, it uses the same code to handle GoogleApiClient but boilerplate code may be a factor. I'd like to know of precautions for using GoogleApi in the context of a service. I'll try to make a test project with your suggestion.

Comment: None other than remembering to unsubscribe in `onDestroy()` that I know of. I use it in a service myself. Just to throw another library into the mix, then I use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to broadcast whenever new locations are available to update UI. This works almost like regular broadcasts but is not limited to serializable data but works for any complex object plus it takes less code than setting up broadcastreceivers etc.

Comment: @cYrixmorten event EventBus seems great. I read about it before but forgot its name and never used it. It's good to see the project is still active.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I don't know what to think. I'm just doing a couple of tests with ReactiveLocation. I modified the sample project and added a service similar to the one in this question. I left the original settings (500 millis of update time) and worked for an hour (not so much time, but worked). Then I just changed settings to 30 seconds = 30000 millis and it got killed in just half hour exactly but started again thanks to START_STICKY, but got no more locations. I re-build the project back to 500 millis and restarted the phone. 5 hours later it still gives GPS chip locations.

Comment: @cYrixmorten My version has given GPS for more time but makes me wonder if the problem is in setInterval. I thought the bigger this setting the better for battery and precision.

Comment: Well, the smaller the interval the better precision, bigger values less battery consumption... It is hard to tell what the problem may be, in my app I receive location updates every 5 seconds, and if the device has moved more than 20 meters, then it updates UI (using the EventBus broadcast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of testing I can tell the "problem" is device dependent. My app worked fine on a friend's Nexus 4 by long time.

I also made it work in my Xperia SP by changing the update interval

```
miLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(5000)
```

May be I can set it to a higher interval. I'm just sure 30 seconds is too much.

My best guess to cover my client's devices is to set some shared preference where this interval can be set in case the GPS chip stops giving locations.